# Concealability of a Hidden Arm Slide

Tags: shadowrun-sr4

Does the "Hidden Arm Slide" weapon accessory modify the concealability of a weapon at all?  The brief description in the rulebook only discusses drawing the weapon as a free action but doesn't touch on concealability.  The "Hidden" part of the name makes me thing it should, but a heavy pistol up the sleeve is pretty noticeable, I would think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't think so, because it doesn't actually make the weapon smaller, or protect it from a scan. It just makes it easier to draw when it's concealed. If it doesn't mention in the book that it affects concealment, it's probably best to assume that it doesn't. The only exception would be that if it's built into a cyberarm, obviously it would be concealed within the cyberarm.

Answer (score 0):

SR4 has changed the mechanics of item concealment quite a bit compared to its predecessors. Prior to SR4 most equipment and especially all weapons had a rating for how hard/easy it's to hide this particular item. Mounting weapon modifications, e.g. sights, would make it easier to spot the weapon. There was also gear to help in hiding weapons, e.g. concealed gun holster, which provides a bonus for hiding pistol sized weapons.

However that bonus was always considered to be applicable **only** when you actually take effort in hiding your stuff. Obviously a heavy pistol in your hand is not concealed at all. Even a concealed gun holster would be a dead give away, if you don't wear a jacket over it.
In this Interpretation the Hidden Arm Slide is "hidden" itself and helps in hiding your gun up your sleeve. Apart from making your gun accessible via a free action, it's more or less fluff that should enable you to actually hide your gun at all with no further bonuses implied.

For heavy pistols you should ask your GM, if your sleeves are wide enough to operate the arm slide. I guess short of a kimono very few clothing has wide enough sleeves to hide a heavy pistol, let alone operate the slide.